# Where can I find Magical Taruruuto-kun?

Tags: magical-taruruuto-kun

I'm looking for a manga called *Magical Taruruuto-kun*, but I can't find any book or DVD, just Famicom games.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is material from 1990 the only way you can acquire it is second hand. I found plenty of offers for the Famicon games and manga on **[Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XMagical+Taruruuto+kun.TRS0&_nkw=Magical+Taruruuto+kun&_sacat=0)**.

Comment: Thank you, I have misspelled my sentence I would say that I have just founded games

Comment: well, [take a look at this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MAGICAL-TARURUTO-KUN-EGAWA-TATSUYA-ANIME-MANGA-BOOK-16-/170646622663) seems like I did have luck